# OS X Execute a script while printing

Tags: terminal, applescript, bash, script, printing

Is it possible to make OS X execute a script when document is printed ?

My printer is connected to a power switch which is controlled with a REST API and the idea is to switch the printer on only when it is needed (basically while printing).

Any command (bash, AppleScript) can be used if it can make a call to a rest API (http://10.10.0.1/switchon).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Common Unix Printing System

macOS uses the [Common Unix Printing System](https://www.cups.org/index.html) (CUPS) for printing. This open source system does allow for calling scripts and more.

Knowing this, the search for [`cups pre-print script`](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=cups+pre-print+script&t=osx&ia=qa) returns some good starting points.

## Virtual Printer to Real Printer Workflow

The StackOver questions [Programming a Filter/Backend to 'Print to PDF' with CUPS from any Mac OS X application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11192396/programming-a-filter-backend-to-print-to-pdf-with-cups-from-any-mac-os-x-appli) and [Run a script on files sent to a CUPS print queue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11998935/run-a-script-on-files-sent-to-a-cups-print-queue) offer an example where a virtual printer is used to pre-process a print job before passing it onto a real printer.

In your situation, the pre-processing could be to power on your printer via the REST API.

#### Alternatively…

See also [Run command before and after printing with CUPS?](https://serverfault.com/questions/208268/run-command-before-and-after-printing-with-cups)